# html2canvas doesn't capture the whole <div> with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I'm working on building a meme generator web app using bootstrap to make the web page responsive.

Here is the image that supposed to be captured (works well on phone screens):
[image]

The image that I usually get (happens on PC screens) It's a white image:
[image]

here is my html code for the `div` that I need to capture:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="theUserMeme">

        <div class="row">

            <p id="memeWords">
                When I see something lol 

            </p>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <img id = "memeImage" src="images/init meme.jpg">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Also, this is my JavaScript function that is called when the button is clicked to capture the `div`:

```
function generateMeme(){

    window.scrollTo(0,0);

    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#theUserMeme")).then(canvas => {
        
        var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1);
        console.log(image);
        
        alert(image);

        document.getElementById("finalImageCopy").src = image;
    });


}
```

Why this happens depending on the size of the screen? What should I do to make it working in every screen size? If bootstrap is not a good choice for html2canvas, what should be better?

Comment: Have you waited for the image to load before calling htm2canvas? If not you may get a blank canvas - would depend on caching etc.

Comment: @AHaworth Do you mean wait for the web page to be loaded? Yes, I've waited. If you mean wait for the final image, I also waited. It seems that html2canvas can't read that div

Answer (score 0):

for external images try using  **useCORS: true,**
[enter link description here](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).